# teb local planner

Tags: ros, source, planner, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Following my other question link: [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/226880/teb-local-planner-installation/) , I am now trying to install teb_local_planner on ROS Hydro from source.

I am not sure on how to install packages from source so I have been following the answer to this question link:[here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10581/installing-ros-packages-from-source/).

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/hydro
rosinstall operating on /home/powerbot67/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/hydro
(Over-)Writing /home/powerbot67/ros/.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /home/powerbot67/ros

rosinstall update complete.
```

> Now, type `source /home/powerbot67/ros/setup.bash` to
> set up your environment. Add that to
> the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` to set
> it up every time.
>
> If you are not using bash please see
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall/NonBashShells

```
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ echo "source ~/ros/setup.bash">> ~/.bashrc
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ roslocate info teb_local_planner > teb_local_planner.rosinstall
Using ROS_DISTRO: hydro
rosinstall ~/ros teb_local_planner.rosinstall
    cannot locate information about teb_local_planner

powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~$ rosinstall ~/ros teb_local_planner.rosinstall
rosinstall operating on /home/powerbot67/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  teb_local_planner.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing /home/powerbot67/ros/.rosinstall
    (Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /home/powerbot67/ros

rosinstall update complete.
```

Is this the correct way to install teb_local_planner from source on Hydro? Or does this mean that teb_local_planner cannot be installed on Hydro?

Thanks always.

Update: Tried installing teb_local_planner from source as suggested by @gvdhoorn but I am getting the following errors:

```
powerbot67@powerbot67-desktop:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro=hydro
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
if test "x`dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status} ${Version}\n' libaria-sourcedep`" != 'xlibaria-sourcedep install ok installed 2.8.0-1'; then
  echo "libaria-sourcedep not installed"
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi

}}}

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
teb_local_planner: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [costmap_converter]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227093/teb-local-planner/) by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-24**:
It would be much simpler if you use `catkin` tool. I think that catkin is default since Hydro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is this the correct way to install teb_local_planner from source on Hydro?

No.

Quickly:

```
# create a catkin workspace somewhere (if you already have one, skip this)
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/src

# get a copy of teb_local_planner
git clone https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner.git

# make sure we have all prerequisites
# NOTE: this step may fail
rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro=hydro

# now build
# NOTE: this step may fail
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

If that is successful (no errors) then it may/should work. Source the `setup.bash` of the workspace (`source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`) and use `teb_local_planner` as you would as if it had been installed using `apt-get`.

---

Edit:

> ```
> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
> ```

```
teb_local_planner: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [costmap_converter]
```

The problem is that `costmap_converter` is *also* not released into Hydro (see [wiki/costmap_converter](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_converter)). You'll have to try and see whether you can build that from source on Hydro as well. Just place [the package](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/costmap_converter.git) in the same workspace as where you have `teb_local_planner`. But again: no guarantees that this will work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-19**:
I will try it out. Thanks once again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-20**:
Just curious btw: do you have any particular reason to use Hydro? It's been EOL for some time now, and (fi) `teb_local_planner` would be trivial to install on newer ROS versions (a simple `apt-get install ..`).

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-20**:
I am using ROS as part of a project to fulfill the requirements to obtain my degree in Engineering. My project builds upon work done by past students which was all done using ROS Hydro. If I update the ROS version, I'll have to repeat all past work, no?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-20**:
(1/2)

> If I update the ROS version, I'll have to repeat all past work, no?

It depends: if they didn't use anything that was *specific* to Hydro, then updating to Indigo would probably not be too much work. I can't guarantee anything, but you could at least try to compile 'past work' on Indigo.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-20**:
(2/2) Most Hydro packages work pretty well on Indigo. But I can't make the decision for you, you'll have to decide for yourself whether the amount of work to check if things work on Indigo + any potential work upgrading pkgs that don't work <= struggling with Hydro.

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-20**:
(1/2) Considering that I don't have much time left and that the main aim is to get the robot to autonomously navigate a known map in a populated environment, I think it's better to keep using Hydro. I have noticed that eband_local_planner is similar and has documentation for Hydro.

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-02-20**:
(2/2) Do you think you can help me with this question? http://answers.ros.org/question/227098/using-eband_local_planner-with-move_base/